# How to extract a vector by 100+ unique character strings without having to type all of them by hand in R

Tags: r, vector

I have a data set of more than 86,000 different rows and 27 variables. It is a list of different individuals, their company, percentage attendance, among other things. Each company has data from 2010-2011 starting in September all the way to 2015-2016.

A portion of the data set is below with omissions and ellipses to indicate transitions.

```
yr      Company month MO    % Attendance    %Change
2010-11 "015JK" 1    SEP    88.21   
2010-11 "015JK" 2    OCT    92.51             4.31
2010-11 "015JK" 3    NOV    90.97            -1.54
2010-11 "015JK" 4    DEC    89.19            -1.78
2010-11 "015JK" 5    JAN    86.88            -2.31
2010-11 "015JK" 6    FEB    89.28             2.4
```

...

```
yr        Company  month MO % Attendance     %Change
2015-2016  015JK    1   JAN   82    
2015-2016  015JK    2   FEB   64               -18
2015-2016  015JK    3   MAR   94                30
2015-2016  015JK    4   APRIL 98                4
2015-2016  015JK    5   MAY   50                -48
2015-2016  015JK    6   JUNE  68                18
```

This is a typical set of data whereupon we start again but this time we start with a new company as such:

```
yr           Company    month   MO    %Attendance          %Change
2010-2011    0184JK     1       JAN     49  
2010-2011    0184JK     2       FEB     52                   3
2010-2011    0184JK     3       MAR     82                   30
2010-2011    0184JK     4       APRIL   55                  -27
2010-2011    0184JK     5       MAY     53                   -2
2010-2011    0184JK     6       JUNE    80                   27
```

...

```
yr           Company    month   MO     %Attendance      %Change
2015-2016    0184JK      1      JAN        87   
2015-2016    0184JK      2      FEB        47              -40
2015-2016    0184JK      3      MAR        61               14
2015-2016    0184JK      4      APRIL      78               17
2015-2016    0184JK      5      MAY        43              -35
2015-2016    0184JK      6     JUNE        85               42
```

I can capture these sets of data relatively easily from the massive 86,000 row datasheet with the following *R* codes

```
015JK <- df[ which( df$Company== "015J"), ]
0184JK <- df[ which( df$Company== "0184JK"), ]
```

The problem is that that I have more than 100 plus companies and it would be onerous to type in 90+ iterations of

```
some company name such as 015JK <-df[ which(df$company== "some company      
name"), ]
```

Is there way to extract the unique values of Company and then input it into a multiple iterations of the following aforementioned variety:

```
some company code name such as 015JK <-df[ which(df$company== "some company      
code"), ]
```

Comment: I don't know why you wanna do that, but one way to archieve it would be `lst <- split(df, df$Company); list2env(lst, .GlobalEnv)`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you plan to do with the subsetted data sets, but perhaps `dplyr::group_by` helps you?

Comment: lukeA it did exactly as I wanted but it deleted or removed the other datasets from the global Environment. How could I retrieve them?

Comment: The answer is simple: Do not do this. I repeat, do not split your dataset into individual datasets. There is absolutely no reason for doing this. Everything you want to do, you can do better with the data together in one object.

Comment: K. Thanks. I will refrain from doing this.